# Avoid formatting code on paste Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I copy and paste the code with Visual Studio, it will auto-format the pasted code (for example, it removes some extra spaces that I have intentionally added for clarity)

I just want that the code is pasted as I copied it, just like a normal text editor does. What I copy it's what I paste :)

Is it possible to just disable the auto-format on paste?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, to paste text from the clipboard without reformatting applicable to any language, you can use the following C# command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    ts.Insert(System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can turn off the Text Editor - C# - Formatting - General - **Automatically format on paste** option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that it's for C++. For C++ there is a "folder option" called "When I paste" and I have it set to "Do nothing" but still the code is modified when I paste it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for html though (razor views specifically) :S