# Visual Studio 2019 add attribute when paste code

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2019

Does anyone know how to stop Visual Studio 2019 formatting when paste code? Currently I already untick the check box for auto formating when paste code. But when I paste code form other source, It still add some attribute to my existing code. For example, I copy the bellow code from other source:

`<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="test"> ... </script>`

After I paste, Visual studio auto add in `checked=checked` for my existing code:

```
 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="other">
 <div>
   //before paste look like this
   //<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" onclick="Action_Clicked(this)" checked=checked checked=checked checked/><span class="slider round"></span></label>
      
   //after paste become this         
   <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" onclick="Action_Clicked(this)" checked=checked checked=checked checked=checked checked=checked checked=checked checked=checked checked=checked/><span class="slider round"></span></label>

 </div>
      

 </script>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341325/avoid-formatting-code-on-paste-visual-studio-2015